# Custom Helper Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello Currently I just worked out the way I would like to load my views in an array but it is the long way of typing.

How would I be best to create a helper file / function that would let me still type in header and footer etc and pick up views but with out me type full length in controller.

Currently I have to type this way

Works This Way Just To Long Though

```
$this->children = array(
   'header' => $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/header.tpl'),
   'column_left' => $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/column_left.tpl'),
   'column_right' =>  $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/column_right.tpl'),
    'content_top' => $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/content_top.tpl'),
    'content_bottom' => $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/content_bottom.tpl'),
    'footer' => $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/footer.tpl')
```

);

```
$this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/home.tpl' , $this->children);
```

I would like a helper file that I can call so in the controller all I have to type is. It just makes it easier if I don't have to put the full view name in that's where helper would come in

```
public function index() {

    $this->load->helper('template'); "This is the name I have chosen"

    $this->children = array(
    'header',
    'column_left',
    'column_right',
    'content_top',
    'content_bottom',
    'footer'
    );

    $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/home.tpl' , $this->children);

}
```

Comment: please the best options is to move to hmvc concept as the loading time  for this method would increase in any way you do it check the hmvc feature

Comment: I have use hmvc not what I am after sorry

Comment: I have used hmvc in the past not what I am after right now. Trying to set my codeigniter template/theme just like open cart but they use custom template engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('final_view'))
{
    //$data - CI custom $data (from controller to views)
    //$views - an array with your children views
    function final_view($data, $views = array())
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        //Include each views
        foreach($views as $view)
        {
            $CI->load->view('theme/default/template/common/'.$view.'.tpl');
        }

        //Include the main view tpl and the custom CI $data
        $CI->load->view('theme/default/template/common/home.tpl', $data);
    }   
}
```

EDIT : As tomexsans said, I added CI instance.

Comment: this would throw out an error, using this when not in object context or something like that. the helper is not linked with the core controller, so you can't just call `$this`, correct me if i'm wrong/

Comment: but I still would like to be able to call my $this->children array header etc in controller.

Comment: Please do explain where

Comment: Where you have now corrected them. But you left it there for 15 minutes with syntax and logical errors and other amenities (like the wrong function name)

Comment: I have just created controllers for each of the other views header, footer, column_left, column_right, content_top, content_bottom. And have included there view file in there controller. How would I make it so that whey I type up the array like above it will pick up the controller.

Comment: What you are asking sounds like HMVC and not MVC. If you want to load the controller Header because there is a header view + controller FOO because there is foo view, then go for HMVC, you can't do this in MVC unless you extends Codeigniter [see here](https://www.google.fr/search?q=HMVC+codeigniter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=JaDeUtvwBoeK1AXG4YHgAg) or you can also use other frameworks built on CodeIgniter with native HMVC : Kohana and PHPixies

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to use a helper since you will be needing `core` functions, just create a new core and extend every controller with it

then you can do something likethis (not yet tested), but it will be dynamic, granting you always use the `header,column_left,column_right,content_top,content_bottom,footer` combinations on your code

```
//param 1 is the config of the view
// param 2 is the data to be passed on the view
function final_view($view,$data)
{   

    //set all path views
    $header['with_stars'] = 'path to view';
    $header['without_bg'] = 'path to view';
    $header['big_title'] = 'path to view';

    $column_left['black'] = 'path to view';
    $column_left['blue'] = 'path to view';
    $column_left['red'] = 'path to view';


    $column_right['big_right'] = 'path to view';
    $column_right['small_right'] = 'path to view';

    $content_top['big_blue_top'] = 'path to view';
    $content_top['small_red_top'] = 'path to view';


    $content_bottom['no_title'] = 'path to view';
    $content_bottom['with_title'] = 'path to view';


    $footer['with_copyright'] = 'path to view';
    $footer['with_big_date'] = 'path to view';


    //combine in one array
    $glue = [
      'header' => $this->load->view($header[$view[0]]),
      'column_left' => $this->load->view($column_left[$view[1]]),
      'column_right' => $this->load->view($column_right[$view[2]]),
      'content_top' => $this->load->view($content_top[$view[3]]),
      'content_bottom' => $this->load->view($content_bottom[$view[4]]),
      'footer' => $this->load->view($footer[$view[5]]),
      'data' => $data
    ];
    // you could do other stuff here before loading the view
    $this->load->view('path_to_view',$glue);
}
```

Instead of loading the views you can just do this

```
//header,column_left,column_right,content_top,content_bottom,footer
$view = array('with_stars','black','big_right','big_blue_top','with_title','with_big_date');
$data['somedata'] = 'data as string';
$data['somedata2'] = array('data as string','some array');

// you could do other stuff here before loading the view
$this->final_view($view,$data);
```

Comment: with my array it way I am after. I trying to get it similar to open cart setup. With there template system. Other codeigniter template engines not what I am after.